# VBS to Create Desktop Shortcut with RunAs Arguments

Tags: vbscript, windows-7-x64, runas

My Goal: I am trying to use VBS to create a desktop shortcut for IE under the current user running it with using the RunAs command with arguments and a variable (InputBox) prompt that fills in the variable with the user's input.

OS: Win7 x64

Working BAT: (filling in the domain\username manually)

```
%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:Domain\Username "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

NON-working VBS:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
strUser = InputBox ("Please Enter your Domain Account")
set oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\RunAs Internet Explorer (Domain Account).lnk")
oUrlLink.TargetPath = ("%windir%\system32\runas.exe" /u:DOMAIN\"" & strUser & "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")
oUrlLink.IconLocation = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
oUrlLink.Save
```

Comment: You need to correct escape the string in the `TargetPath`, when using quotes inside a string, double them is the rule like `oUrlLink.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:DOMAIN\" & strUser & " ""%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"""`.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the `TargetPath` is not a valid string, when breaking in and out of strings they should always start and end with a single double quote. Also literal quotes inside a string have to be escaped in order to avoid "breaking" the string and causing a syntax error. To escape a literal quote in a string double it.

Here are some examples that should help.

```
Dim TestString
TestString = "Simple string"
'Simple string
TestString = "Concatenated" & " string"
'Concatenated string
TestString = "Another " & TestString & " with a variable"
'Another Concatenated string with a variable
TestString = """Quoted string"""
'"Quoted string"
TestString = "This is a """ & TestString & """ in a variable"
'This is a "Quoted string" in a variable
```

With this in mind, the line should have been

```
oUrlLink.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:DOMAIN\" & strUser & " ""%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"""
```

Output as:

```
%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:DOMAIN\Username "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

---

Following on from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307239/vbs-to-create-desktop-shortcut-with-runas-arguments/42313185?noredirect=1#comment71852719_42313185)

Sorry focused on the wrong issue, while that was a problem the main issue was how you were setting `TargetPath`. It should only contain the path to the executable any arguments need to be specified with `Arguments` property, so give this a try.

```vb
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
strUser = InputBox ("Please Enter your Domain Account")
set oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\RunAs Internet Explorer (Domain Account).lnk")
oUrlLink.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\runas.exe"
'Use arguments to pass any arguments for the executable.
oUrlLink.Arguments = "/u:DOMAIN\" & strUser & " ""%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"""
oUrlLink.IconLocation = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
oUrlLink.Save
```

Comment: Thank you Lankymart! It still seems there is an error...


Error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create Desktop Shortcut (RunAs Internet Explorer (Doamin Account).vbs(5, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

It is prompting the input box string, but failing on the execution. I have also tried to separate the last space & arguments with the same exact error :(

Comment: seperated string....


        oUrlLink.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:DOMAIN\" & strUser & " " & "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

Comment: @GekkoLlama Again that won't work because the `%ProgramFiles%` will expand to `Program Files` which means you need to enclose it in quotes *(a quoted string, see examples)*, so following the advice in the answer, it should be `oUrlLink.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:DOMAIN\" & strUser & " ""%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"""`. It doesn't format well in a comment, just copy the line in my answer - *"With this in mind, the line should have been"*.

Comment: I did copy & paste your 'With this in mind, the line should have been' answer, this is where the error is coming from. I have tried this on multiple machines with the same error.

Comment: Script:

    set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    strUser = InputBox ("Please Enter your Domain Account")
    set oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\RunAs Internet Explorer (strUser).lnk")
    oUrlLink.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:DOMAIN\" & strUser & " ""%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"""
    oUrlLink.IconLocation = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
    oUrlLink.Save

Comment: Also, please keep in mind im trying to understand this with 0 prior VBS knowledge, so im grasping from scratch. be easy on me :)

Comment: @GekkoLlama understood, to be honest, I was focusing on the wrong thing. It was an issue but ran it myself and realised what the problem was, see updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! :)

How would you make the name line variable as well?

I an trying...set oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\RunAs Internet Explorer (strUser).lnk")

Also tried...set oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\RunAs Internet Explorer (" & strUser & ")".lnk")

Comment: Got it :D................


    set oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\RunAs Internet Explorer (" & strUser & ").lnk")